# Quasar Framework: How to blur background in q-dialog?

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I want to blur the background when clicking the q-dialog. any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would do is to extend the *q-dialog__backdrop* class

```
<style>
  .q-dialog__backdrop
  {
    backdrop-filter: blur(7px);
  }
</style>
```